# Keras model: validation acc is shaking chaotically in train vs val graph

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Machine Learning and Keras and I am trying to solve a multi-class classification problem. Currently I am trying to improve my CNN model.

I plotted validation and training accuracies and the effect observed seems a bit strange to me. The training acc increases and remains constant, while the validation acc also increases but has points in which is very low.

Do you have any ideas why this might be happening?

Here is the graph: 
[image]

Comment: Looks like overfitting. provide more details like What's your configuration? How much data was used for validation? data size?

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati I have 930 training samples with a 0.01 validation split. The size of the data is (930, 52, 72, 1). This is a link to a photo of my architecture and settings: https://docs.google.com/document/d/191ruXKW9SsyDRES_MSZcog-cH0LtjQzh_H3QXnNH8SM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I know that if the model is overfitting then usually in the training vs validation graph these two accuracies will diverge. However mine don't clearly diverge, the validation acc is more like shaking. I don't know, it looks a bit dubious to me.

Comment: validation split is 0.01? if that is correct then you have only 9 images for validation and the validation error is expected to vary but the variation in way too much in your case. Dropping accuracy from ~90 to almost 0. Can you try to use `ImageDataGenerator` class to augment images. Bast approach is to collect more data if possible

Comment: Thanks! I will try the ImageDataGenerator. What would be a good validation split? In addition, can you say whether or not the model is overfitting based on what you saw? Or is it the case that this can't be clearly stated just based on the graphs.

Comment: It can be stated looking at the graph. But I have never used 0.01 split when I had very limited data and so I don't know how it looks. One question. Did you normalize data? when there is limited data, try to use 20 to 25% for validation. Generally, if you have 40000 data then you could use 10%. try playing with the regularizer also.

Comment: I did normalize the data. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I think data normalization is the root-cause I guess

Comment: As data normalization I divided the pixels by 255.0.